# Query and filter many to many in Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDb (and No-SQL in general) and still having some troubles designing my data model.

I have the following use case. Imagine an app that handles events. 
Users can attend an event. Events can be attended by several users.
I need to be able to tell who is going to which event and what events a User will go to.

So, far I have come with the following solution:

- I have a `Users` table with unique ID
- an `Events` table with unique ID
- An `EventAttendeeds` table with

  - `EventId` and `UserId` fields
  - Primary Key on EventId(HASH) + UserId(RANGE) => Allows me to tell Who is going to a given Event
  - a Global secondary Index on UserId (HASH) + EventId (RANGE) => Allows to tell me What events a User will go to.

So far so good. The issue occurs when I need to tell what Events a user will go to for a given month, order by date.
e.g:  What events will user 123 go to this month (to show it in a calendar for example).

The only option that came to my mind is to denormalize the data and add a copy of the `eventDate` field from my Events table to the EventAttendees table and then add a Global Secondary Index on `UserId` (HASH) + `eventDate` (RANGE).

I don't like this solution too much because of the hard work of keeping data in sync (e.g: If the event date changes I need to update **all** the records related to that event in the `EventAttendeeds` table).

Is there another way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Keep in mind that a user could be attending dozens of events. Doing the filtering in memory is not really a good option either.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Another option that came to my mind. 
Usually, an event will not be attended to by more than a handful of Users. 
So I was thinking in getting rid of the "join table" which in a NoSql Database would make more sense, I guess. 
The issue with that is at the time of querying the DB when I need to find events for a given user. That would force the use of a filter expression; which could slow down the query. What other options do I have?
I was also thinking using Elastic Search for searching by text, etc. so, I was also considering using it for this purpose (looking for events for a given user for a given month)... I would bring the ids and then use a normal DynamoDb query. That sounds a bit like an overkill though...